# Можно ли открыть сайт из командной строки, так чтобы контент передался в командную строку?

Tags: запрос, командная-строка

Хочу открыть главную страницу stackoverflow с помощью командной строки виндовс.
Команды `start https://ru.stackoverflow.com/` и `explorer "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"`  мне не подходят, потому что они открывают сайт в браузере по умолчанию. Я считаю, что раз командная строка выводит текст, значит она теоретически может вывести (пусть даже в убогой кодировке с краказябрами) web-страницу.

**Вопрос:** какой командной в командной строке можно открыть сайт так, чтобы содержимое веб страницы вывелось в командную строку?

Comment: curl get не вариант

Comment: Попробуйте так curl https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1276526/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
 curl https://ru.stackoverflow.com
```

Стандартный curl. Только вот в консоли получите результат запроса по сути данные, а не распрекрассную страницу

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял... Вы вполне можете открывать веб страницы в вашем терминале. И естественно это не будет выглядеть как в обычном браузере, но информацию читать вы сможете. К примеру есть консольный браузер [Lynx](https://pingvinus.ru/program/lynx) позволяющий открывать веб страницы в терминале.
Например так можно открыть [ru.stackoverflow.com](http://ru.stackoverflow.com) в терминале с помощью lynx:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтобы установить [Lynx](https://pingvinus.ru/program/lynx) введите `sudo apt install lynx`

Comment: Прочитайте вопрос повнимательнее. "командной строки виндовс".

Comment: @Aziz Umarov упс. ашибочка вышла

Comment: @Aziz Umarov кстати. как вариант в меня в wsl это запущено xdd

Comment: Ну да вот теперь это вопрос снимает :)))) Windows sybsytem linux - коммандная строка виндовс